# Broad Question - fluid SVG Line Drawing Animation

Tags: animation, svg

This is a very broad question, and I understand if this is taken down.

Anyhow, I'm looking to animate the water in the following still SVG image, and I'm wondering what advice you may have? Kinda looking for a wiggle effect, and although I originally planned to manually animate each path, I'm wondering if there's any tools out there (that a simple google search hasn't revealed for me).

[image]

Looking forward to any creative solutions, and many thanks!

Comment: Please take a look at this pen where I'm using SVG filters to animate the water. https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/oYMxqe You will need 2 images: one for the water and another one for the boat, and you'll animate only the water

Comment: @enxaneta Cheers this has worked beautifully - need's finsessing, but I thought you'd like to see a preview https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YOEXGp

Comment: @enxaneta Sadly not finding it to be cross-browser friendly, I'll update you if we find a fix.

Comment: (Tried in both Firefox and Edge)

Comment: strange: it works for me on Chrome, FF & Opera. On Safari you get a still image with the displacement in place. It also works on Edge and even on IE, although the displacement is not that significant. I'm sorry it didn't work for you.

Comment: @enxaneta Probably version dependant? (what browser Vs are you on?) I've just got it working by importing the SVG layers directly (apparently nested SVGs are supported). Firefox and Edge don't seem to like this SVG tag `<image id="blueMoon" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/images/boats-underlay.svg?v=3"></image>`

Comment: Should it interest you, this is my completed setup - https://i.imgur.com/J40bZjk.png I don't know if we'll use this yet, but I have found this interesting to play with. Thanks for your help!